# BOBJ. RESTful Web Service API. Change Data Source of Data Provider

Tags: rest, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I'm trying to change a data source of a data provider using the following RESTful API functionality.

[Changing the Data Objects of a Data Provider](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_BUSINESSOBJECTS_WEB_INTELLIGENCE/d6bd74f8532c4e978419c7300bda43f8/ec5653cc6fdb101497906a7cb0e91070.html?version=4.1.11) ([old link](http://help.sap.com/saphelpiis_sbo41sp4wi-sdk/frameset.htm?ec5653cc6fdb101497906a7cb0e91070.html))

I get the proposed mappings and then post a request to change the data source. I get back a message that the document was successfully updated, but the actual data source of the data provider is not changed.

I wonder if I'm missing anything or need to do something else to get the data source updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you still need to save the changes made to the document. This is described [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelpiis_sbo41sp4wi-sdk/frameset.htm?45f8a4b26e041014910aba7db0e91070.html).

After the data source change, your document will have its state changed from *Unused* or *Original* to *Modified*. By issuing a `PUT` request to `<webiURL>/documents/{documentId}`, you would save the changes back to the repository.

Comment: Have you ever had a problem with the reports after you updated then using a PUT request? 

I'm changing the datasource for the whole report and then use PUT request as you suggested to save the changes and it all works fine. Although if I try to change the data source on the same report again, I get a "404" error when I try to get the proposed mappings.

Comment: Actually, if anyone gets the same problem, I think the problem caused by the fact that data providers change their ID after the change on the data source. So DP01 turns into DP02 and so on.

Comment: do you have any idea why update of the data source would come back with success saying that the resource is updated, but then when I try to save the changes using the PUT request (just like you described in your answer) I get back a success message saying that the document has NOT been modified? It happens for some reports, not for all.

Comment: Check the document's state after modifying the data provider (`GET <webiURL>/documents/{documentId}`). This should say `Modified`. The document's details are described [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelpiis_sbo41sp5wi-sdk/frameset.htm?ec5627ba6fdb101497906a7cb0e91070.html) and the lifecycle [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelpiis_sbo41sp5wi-sdk/frameset.htm?5f32f787be7140498239940b89453cc5.html).